# Spring 3.2 - AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer onStartup - adding a servlet filter returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, spring-java-config

I have a purely JavaConfig Java webapp that uses class extending from AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.  It works great for configuring my dispatcher servlet, but my dispatcher servlet is only mapped to requests with the url pattern "/rest/*".  For all other requests (ie css, html, js, etc), there is no spring mapping and everything goes through the default servlet.  For these requests, I want to implement a GZip filter.  I have used a custom gzip filter I found online years ago in many projects.

With the JavaConfig implementation, I understand that the protected Filter[] getServletFilters() method applies to the dispatcher serlvet... is this incorrect?

What I'm trying to do now is apply the gzip filter to any request not going to the dispatcher servlet.  I'm overriding the onStartup method like so:

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);      
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic gzipFilter = servletContext.addFilter("gzipFilter", new GzipFilter());
        gzipFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");   
    }
```

The encoding filter works fine, but I get a NullPointerException on the GzipFilter when I add the mapping... the servletContext.addFilter returns null.  I thought maybe there was something funky with my custom class and the new JavaConfig implementation, so I found online that people were using a gzip filter included with the ehacache-web package, so I added that as a dependency and attempted to use that filter instead.  Same thing... the CharacterEncodingFilter works fine, and the addFilter method properly returns a FilterRegistration.Dynamic object, however the gzip filter still returns null.

Any ideas what is causing this?

EDIT:

Here is my whole config file:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic gzipFilter = servletContext.addFilter("gzipFilter", new GzipFilter());
        gzipFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");


    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SecurityConfig.class, Log4jConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{
            "/rest/*",
            "/index.html",
            "/login.html",
            "/admin.html",
            "/index/*",
            "/login/*",
            "/admin/*"
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter openEntityManagerInViewFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        openEntityManagerInViewFilter.setBeanName("openEntityManagerInViewFilter");
        openEntityManagerInViewFilter.setPersistenceUnitName("HSQL");

        return new javax.servlet.Filter[]{openEntityManagerInViewFilter};
    }

}
```

Regardless if I add the GzipFilter to the getServletFilters() or create the FilterRegistration.Dynamic from the servletContext.addFilter() with a URL mapping of "/*", only requests being processed through the dispatcher servlet are being gzipped.

Edit 2:

Here is a URL that is not being gzipped:

```
http://localhost:8084/swtc/js/ServiceWidget/templates/ServiceWidget.html

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  399
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Mon, 07 Apr 2014 18:47:08 GMT
Etag    W/"399-1377195848751"
Last-Modified   Thu, 22 Aug 2013 18:24:08 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Here is a URL that is being gzipped:

```
http://localhost:8084/swtc/rest/mapServices/getEnabledServices

Response Headers
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  76
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 08 Apr 2014 18:34:11 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Would an option be changing the dispatcher serlvet mapping to /* and just define my js, css, img, etc folders as resources?  I feel like this is skirting the issue though... It would be nice to know why I can specify a filter like I used to in web.xml that has nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: Please post your full stack trace and the rest of your configuration.

Comment: It's simply a NullPointerException.  Before the NPE is generated, the servletContext.addFilter method returns null, when it should return a FilterRegistration.Dynamic.  The NPE results from attempting to call the addMappingforUrlPatterns on the gzipfilter, when gzipFilter is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us as much as I'd like but here's what the javadoc for [`ServletContext#addFilter(String, Filter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addFilter%28java.lang.String,%20javax.servlet.Filter%29) says

> **Returns**: a `FilterRegistration` object that may be used to further
>   configure the given filter, **or `null` if this ServletContext already
>   contains a complete `FilterRegistration` for a filter with the given
>   `filterName` or if the same filter instance has already been registered
>   with this or another ServletContext in the same container**

You seem to have registered that `Filter` or another with the same name already.

Comment: Inspecting the context object shows that there is a gzip filter, which I was registering in the getServletFilters method... So I guess my assumption that the protected Filter[] getServletFilters() method only applies to filters for the dispatcher servlet... either that or the servlet context being passed into onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) method is the dispatcher servlet context.  Either way, I have a good means to figure this out now.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Bal There is only a single `ServletContext` object provided by the Servlet container for each of its web application. Don't get confused by the `ServletContext` provided by the container and the `ApplicationContext` loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`, ie. what Spring calls the servlet context.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was adding a new gzip filter instance in the overridden getServletFilters() method, however I thought that only got mapped to dispatcher servlet requests as I can't specify a URL pattern, which in my case are only urls with the pattern /rest/*. I removed that and added it directly to the ServletContext object with a "/*" pattern, but still, only requests coming from the dispatcher servlet are being zipped. Any request to my /js or /css folders are not being gzipped. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bal Can you post the relevant config as an edit? `/*` will match all requests, including those handled by the dispatcher servlet. I can't tell why they aren't matching your other ones. Also, give an example of the URLs that you see are matched and those that aren't.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I have posted my web config and example URLs, along with their corresponding response headers. Please let me know if you want to see anything else.

Comment: @Bal Add the `GzipFilter` implementation too while you're at it.

Comment: I was using a custom one, but I switched to the ehcache-web gzip filter:  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-web/2.0.4/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/web/filter/GzipFilter.java

Comment: @Bal I don't see anything wrong with your configuration. I don't have access to a PC right now, but try debugging the `GzipFilter` on those requests that doesn't get gzipped.